# How to expand the scope of Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `customer` in my PostgreSQL database. I want to select records that have a country listed and if the country is US, there needs to be a state listed. Below is my query that just selects for US rows.

```
SELECT
    id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    address1,
    state,
    country,
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    country <> ''
    AND id IN (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            customer
        WHERE
            country = 'US'
            AND state IS NOT NULL
            AND state <> '');
```

How do I change the query so that I get customers from all countries, not just US customers?

Comment: You should have a constraint that makes sure no `''` states are stored. Use null instead of those.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select records that have a country listed and if the country is US, there needs to be a state listed.

This seems like a `where` clause with no subquery:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where c.country <> 'US' or c.state is not null;
```

If `state` can be the empty string, you can use:

```
select c.*
from customer c
where c.country <> 'US' or c.state <> '';
```

This also filters out `NULL`s.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help!